# How to use IoC with generated WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do people often use IoC with WinForm applications? Any best practices?

I'm asking, because Visual Studio generates a lot of code for WinForms and uses parameterless constructor for designer, then how I'm supposed to inject my dependencies into my form? Should I always create another constructor and use it instead, and leave parameterless for designer to manage, or inject my dependencies through attributes?

Comment: Very clear that you already know the solution to leave a parameterless constructor. Then what are you asking for?

Comment: The reason for this question is because I know more than one solution, but don't know drawbacks for either of them. Thats why I ask for best practices.

Comment: IoC in WinForms is an interresting topic, because it is definitely not dead, (.NET Core 3.0 !) and existing solution are sorely missing some Designer support.
I managed to achieve a full design time support by using mocks in a way they are used by the Designer instead of the one that are actually injected during runtime.
The tip consists in a bool check in the user controls and forms constructors to check whether I am in design time or not, so I can set a mock instead of getting instance from the IoC container.

Answer (score 1):

Having used Autofac IoC in a WinForms project, we always had a main constructor with dependencies and a second parameterless constructor just for designer, which was explicitly marked as such using comments. This constructor may even be commented out after you're done with the active "designing" phase to be on the safe side.

I would definitely stay away from using property injection, as it's much easier to reason about and less error-prone to manage constructor parameters.